# How to set $PATH for IntelliJ (on mac)?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to change the $PATH that IntelliJ sees on Mac? I believe it is possible but do not remember how. Thank you!

(I use the LSP Support plugin that invokes executables (specified with an absolute path) that, in turn, try to invoke other commands expecting to find them on the $PATH and failing because /user/local/bin is not on the default path.)